# Identification of 3-pin device from electronic piano

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

Can you identify this device, please? This is at the entrance circuit of an electronic piano.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: fixed the post for you. Next time, don't remove the image-including code!

Comment: You might attract the attention of someone who knows if your title lists the part number and that it's a 3-pin SMD chip.

Comment: Do you have a picture of the wider PCB area, that contained the component?

Comment: Probably just a FET.  Check the circuit where it was and see if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you all for my first post, I believe it's X13B33 P-channel FET, and AO3401A will substitute it. I found this link https://www.yoycart.com/Product/40000634916/. Thanks again!

Comment: Write your findings into an answer and accept it once the system allows.